# errorplot coupled by shaded region of the dataset

Tags: plotting, filling

I have a dataset with errors. I use "ListErrorPlot" to plot the data with the subquent errorbars. Now I need to shade the the data region. The shaded region will include data with error bars only.
Following is my code:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

data = {{0, 1, 0.17}, {5, 1.4, 0.27}, {10, 1.95, 0.23}, {15, 2.05, 
    0.18}, {20, 2.55, 0.21}, {25, 3.01, 0.28}, {30, 3.76, 0.11}};

ErrorListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Hue[0.6, 1, 1]}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledCircle], 15}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.002]], 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", Black, FontFamily -> "Arial", 
    FontSize -> 20], 
   Style["y", Black, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 20]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 32}, {0.8, 4.1}}, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> 400, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 15}]
```

How can I do it? Please help me to get rid of this.
Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what exactly you are trying to achieve. Could you somehow provide an example of what you want? E.g. take the plot you have now, and indicate the shading you want in Paint or similar.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is what you want

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"] // Quiet

data = {{0, 1, 0.17}, {5, 1.4, 0.27}, {10, 1.95, 0.23}, {15, 2.05, 
    0.18}, {20, 2.55, 0.21}, {25, 3.01, 0.28}, {30, 3.76, 0.11}};

Show[
 ErrorListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Hue[0.6, 1, 1]}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {●, 15}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.002]], 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["x", Black, FontFamily -> "Arial", 
     FontSize -> 20], 
    Style["y", Black, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 20]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 32}, {0.8, 4.1}}, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
  ImageSize -> 400, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 15}],
 ListLinePlot[{{#[[1]], Total@Rest@#} & /@ 
    data, {#[[1]], Subtract @@ Rest@#} & /@ data}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, PlotStyle -> None]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Use `Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, LightRed}`, reverse the order of the plots, and move the graphics options into the `Show`, e.g.,

```
Show[
 ListLinePlot[{
   {#[[1]], Total@Rest@#} & /@ data,
   {#[[1]], Subtract @@ Rest@#} & /@ data},
  Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, LightRed}},
  PlotStyle -> None],
 ErrorListPlot[data,
  PlotStyle -> {Hue[0.6, 1, 1]},
  PlotMarkers -> {●, 15}],
 Frame -> True,
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.002]],
 FrameLabel ->
  (Style[#, Black, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 20] & /@ {"x", "y"}),
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 32}, {0.8, 4.1}},
 FrameTicks -> Automatic,
 ImageSize -> 400,
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 15}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `FillingStyle -> LightRed` in the revised `Show`.

Comment: thank you. This is what I exactly wanted

Comment: @ Bob I am facing a minor issue while chnaging the shaded color. I write Filling -> {1 -> {2,LightRed}}; but it does not work, Can you please help me to over come this issue?

Answer (score 3):

If you have version 12.0+, you can also (1) use [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) to pre-process input data, and (2) use `ListPlot` with options [`IntervalMarkers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalMarkers.html) and [`IntervalMarkersStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalMarkersStyle.html):

```
data2 = {#, Around[#2, #3]} & @@@ data;

ListLinePlot[{data2, data2}, IntervalMarkers -> { "Fences", "Bands"}, 
 IntervalMarkersStyle -> {Red, Directive[LineOpacity -> 0, Orange]}, 
 PlotStyle -> Red, PlotMarkers -> {"●", 10}, 
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", Black, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 20], 
     Style["y", Black, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 20]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 32}, {0.8, 4.1}}, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
  ImageSize -> 400, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 15}]
```

[image]